# How to make navbar of bootstrap with few items fit all the page

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm creating a wordpress theme using bootstrap, so I used 320press.com theme. I have a main navbar at the top of the page that includes the following:

- Home
- About Us
- Services
- Gallery
- Contact Us
- The Search box of wordpress

I need to make the list fit with the page, the default layout is insert it to the left close to each other. In other words, I have 6 items, so I need each item takes class "col-sm-2", so each item will fit in two columns.

I write this code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

<a class="navbar-brand" title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('description'); ?>" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Home</a>
    </div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse main-bar">
 <?php wp_bootstrap_main_nav();?>

<?php //if(of_get_option('search_bar', '1')) {?>
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
 div class="form-group">
 <input name="s" id="s" type="text" class="search-query form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<?php _e('Search','wpbootstrap'); ?>" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='<?php echo $typeahead_data; ?>'>
 </div>
 </form>
 <?php //} ?>
</div>

<!-- end .container -->
</div>
```

In CSS, I write the following

```
.main-bar li {
    padding-left: 75px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

It's working fine in wide screen, but in smaller it dose not, such as size 768px or even 1024px.

Comment: Strip your code to bare minimum (remove all the php), or even better, create a bootply or fsfiddle example. Once you'll reproduce it there, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: but i write it with php because i need it by php. it's very easy by using the html code alone !